How to configure rDNS in our instance
Note the domains and domain names in this question are fake, but mirror the set up that we have. I need to know where to configure a reverse DNS record.
We have a server at 198.51.100.1  on the server we have a domain with a website called join.example.com. The server at 198.51.100.1 on the domain join.example.com has a PHP function that connects to a MailerSend (mailersend.com) SMTP account. They send the mail after we send the SMTP call. The mails are sent with the email address noreply@example.com.
Our DNS hosted  at crazydomains.com; example.com hosts an A record to the domain join.example.com to 198.51.100.1 and all other appropriate DNS records on us.com.
Note example.com is linked to other sending methods as well, such as Google mail.
Now for the question, I am not sure which IP addresses I need to set up, and where they should be hosted. Below is what I assume I need to do, but I could be wrong.
198.51.100.1.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR join.example.com. hosted on crazydomains.com domain example.com.

The owner of the zone needs to make any modifications to the PTR records. If that is not the company that you are renting the service from, you can use arin.net to identify the zone owner.

This should be a comment, but it's a bit long.

has a PHP function that connects to a MailerSend (mailersend.com) SMTP account

Do you mean it connects using SMTP?
Why do you think you need to provision a PTR record? I would be very surprised if this is a requirement from Mailsender. Other MX hosts don't see your IP address and only need to see it if you have used an SPF macro depending on it.
Looking at the spf records for join.us.com, I see this:
"v=spf1 include:spf.mailjet.com ~all"

Is that what Mailsender told you to use? I was under the impression that Mailjet and Mailsender were different providers.

Note example.com is linked to other sending methods as well, such as google mail.

Your SPF records do not allow you send email via Google mail.

We have a server at....

Unless you own the net block you cannot provision PTR records.

join.us.com is not the domain we use. It was just a dumby domain, a pretend one. So I was not giving out all our server info.
